# how to access a component with url with parameter and without parameter in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I want to implement accessing one component with two url like
first : "helloworld/search"
second : "helloworld/search/tag"

both take me on same page. with both url it should to call two different function

Comment: can you post yout app-routing module?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: let route :Routes = [  {path: "search/:tag", component:SearchComponent}]

Answer (score 0):

```
You can listen to router events in the component
`this.router.events.forEach((event: NavigationEvent) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (event.url.toLowerCase().endsWith("/tag")) {
         //one function
        }else {
ther function
}
      }`
```